# ICanHaz Not detecting template

Tags: javascript, template-engine, icanhaz.js

I've checked the other posts on this topic, but none of them match my problem. Here is the code for my template:

```
<script id ="postingcell" type="text/html">
    <li class="postinglistcell">
        <div class = "postinfowrapper">
            <table class="centermargins">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="posttitle">{{Title}}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

And here is the code where I call the ICH:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var p = ich["postingcell"](thisobj);
});
```

I can get an error telling me that `ich["postingcell"]` is not defined, but it has been in the above script tag. Does anyone know what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you have a space between `id` and `="postingcell"`. Is this the exact same code?

Comment: it is... but that space should not matter as long as it is outside the string right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ICanHaz also uses jQuery for setting up. One possible reason is your code runs before the **ich.grabTemplates()** call.

```
if (ich.$) {
    ich.$(function () {
        ich.grabTemplates();
    });
}
```

You may try calling **ich.grabTemplates()** in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ich.grabTemplates();
    var p = ich["postingcell"](thisobj);
});
```